# How to find how many concurrent connections per one pageview?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting

My web hosting provider has terms of services saying I can have only 20 concurrent connections.

1 page view = 1 concurrent connections or more?

If 1 page view can have more concurrent connections how to find how many concurrent connections per one page view?

Comment: That would largely depend upon the number of resources referenced in the HTML page such as JavaScript, CSS, Images, etc.

Comment: Um, concurrent connections mean how many people are connecting to your site at the same time. Emphasis on 'same time'. As soon as one user's finished connecting to your site, the concurrent connections will go down by one. So, in your case, only 20 people can connect to your site at the SAME TIME.

Comment: To add to what Jessica said, that doesn't mean the users cannot still be viewing the downloaded page they can. Once the download had finished the connection is cut off unless async off course. Also you can use cdn to host js / css files and that'll be less connections to your server.

Answer (score 1):

If your page doesn't have any external resources (images, CSS, JS), etc then your page view will create only one connection to the server.  Most pages have numerous other resources and different browsers will open different numbers of connections to fetch them.  From [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

```
Firefox 2:  2
Firefox 3+: 6
Opera 9.26: 4
Opera 12:   6
Safari 3:   4
Safari 5:   6
IE 7:       2
IE 8:       6
IE 10:      8
Chrome:     6
```

If some of your resources are from other domains or other sub-domains, browsers will use up to this many connections for each.